# installshield: Windir returns c:\documents & settings\fcuser\windows instead of c:\windows

Tags: 64-bit, windows-server-2003, installshield, rd

we have a setup developed in installshield vr 6.3. it is a self extractable  single setup. it work fine in most on most of the Windows version but on Windows server 2003 64bit in **Execution mode** when doing RD it return user windows directory against WINDIR i.e. **c:\documents & settings\fcuser\windows** instead of **C:\Windows**. According to http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=186499 it should work fine when i change the compatibility bit of Setup but it didn't. i tried changing compatibility bit of these key too (INSTRUN, SETUP and SETUP1 ) but it didn't work either. but when i when i run the setup within the self extractable by extracting it work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield 6.3 is 10 years old, released when Windows 2000 had just come out.  There were no 64-bit Windows OSes at that time.  I'm not surprised you're having trouble.  You really should think about using a modern version of InstallShield, or migrate to something like Wix/NSIS if upgrading is not financially possible.

As I work-around to using WINDIR, you could try getting this Registry value:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRoot

Or try to get the value of this environment variable:
%SYSTEMROOT%